# How to connect an Existing SQL Server Database to Access 2007

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to connect an existing SQL Server EXPRESS datatable (wich I'm using in WebDeveloper 2010) to an Access 2007 database, but I haven't retrieving my datatables.

I'm doing this sequence:

1. In "external data" ribbon, selecting ODBC datasources
2. Linking to datasource using a linked datatable
3. Creating a    new .dsn file SQL Server driver
4. In SQL server field, informing    .\SQLEXPRESS
5. In autentication, selecting NT autentication using network logon

In this step, I supose that the system would show me my database, or a way to inform its path. But I'm not achieving to inform database path, neither selecting my tables. In "change standard database to..." I have only the options: "master", "model", "msdb" and "tempdb". When I try to inform my database path in "Attach database file name", there's an exception "Invalid database". I don't know what should I doing wrong, or how can I solve this issue.

I've been reading about several problems on linking SQL server databases to Access, but to this problem I haven't found a solution, which should be easy. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is it possible your AD user doesn't have access to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you create ODBC connection, check whether you can set default database as the database that you are looking for. If no, then the problem lies some where in the ODBC and you can fix that first and then try to like the table.
2. If you can set the default database in the ODBC Connection, then then problem is likely to be in MS-Access.

Hope this will help you to identify the problem.

Please update the status.

I believe, MS-Access expects timestamp column in the Sql Server table, if you need to update the data.